# Limit of a sequence of sets vs. the limit of their measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, real-numbers

I'm wondering about the theorem on page 16 of J Yeh's Real Analysis. Theorem 1.28 states that:

If both $$\lim_{n\to\infty}E_n \text{ and }\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(E_n)\text{ exist}$$
then, 
$$\mu(\lim_{n\to\infty}E_n)\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(E_n)$$

But I can't seem to think of an example where the inequality is strict. My professor couldn't give me an example after trying for a few minutes. I can see why it should be equality if all the $E_n$ are contained in some finite measure set $A$. Any help in thinking would be appreciated.

Comment: $E_n = [n,n+1)$

Comment: lim = empty? so measure is 0 < 1

Comment: $\bigcup_{n\ge k} E_n = [k,\infty)$, so $\limsup E_n = \bigcap_k \bigcup_{n \ge k} E_n = \emptyset$, hence $\lim E_n = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ has finite measure,  $\mu(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}E_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mu(E_n)$ is true.

Otherwise sets like $E_n=[n,n^2]$, we can have that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}E_n=\varnothing,\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mu(E_n)=+\infty$

The same as Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, which will be taught later in the course. The sequence $\{E_n\}$ is not "uniform converge".